# FabricJS and AngularJS – get and set shadows on active objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fabricjs

I'm extending the `fabric.js` kitchensink with some functions. I try to get and set the active objects shadow properties with no success but I'm sure that I'm missing something trivial. This is what I'm doing in my controllers.js:

#### Setting/Enabling shadows on the selected object:

```
$scope.shadowify = function () {
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (!obj) return;

    if (obj.shadow) {
        obj.shadow = null;
    } else {
        obj.setShadow({
            color: "#000000",
            blur: 10,
            offsetX: 10,
            offsetY: 10
        });
    }
    canvas.renderAll();
};
```

This is working (as it does in the kitchensink example)

#### Getting/Setting the shadows:

```
function getActiveShadow(name) {
    var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (!object) return '';

    return object[name] || '';
}

function setActiveShadow(name, value) {
    var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (!object) return;
    object.setShadow(name, value);
    object.setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

#### and:

```
$scope.setShadowOffsetX = function (value) {
    setActiveShadow('offsetX', value);
    canvas.renderAll();
};


$scope.setShadowOffsetY = function (value) {
    setActiveShadow('offsetY', value);
    canvas.renderAll();
};

$scope.setShadowBlur = function (value) {
    setActiveShadow('blur', value);
    canvas.renderAll();
};

$scope.setShadowColor = function (value) {
    setActiveShadow('color', value);
    canvas.renderAll();
    console.log, (value);
};
```

This is some exemple code from my HTML for binding the values to inputs:

```
<input type="color" 
       id="shadC" 
       value="#455A64" 
       class="small" 
       bind-value-to="shadowColor" 
       ng-model="shadC">


<input type="number" 
       class="small" 
       ng-value="10" 
       id="shadX" 
       skin="condensed" 
       bind-value-to="shadowOffsetX" 
       ng-model="offsetX">
```

No clue what's going on there – when I'm changing the value in my input the whole shadow disappears. This approach is working perfectly for the basic object settings like width/height etc. etc. So I hope it is really something trivial that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Could you create a plnkr or fiddle?

Comment: Thanks for the edits! Will try to put together something, but it is fairly complex to redo this only with the requested code since the whole project is very complicated. Anyhow I will do my best.

Comment: It's always possible to create a minimal fiddle/plnkr to reproduce your problem. We don't need your whole project to reproduce this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getActiveShadow(name) {
    var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (!object) return '';

    return object[name] || '';
}

function setActiveShadow(name, value) {

    var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (!object) return;
    if(object.shadow)
     object.shadow[name] = value;
    else{
     var ob = {};
     ob[name] = value;
     object.setShadow(ob);
    }
    
    object.setCoords();
}
var offsetXVal = 10;
var setShadowOffsetX = function (value) {
    value = offsetXVal+=5;
    setActiveShadow('offsetX', value);
    canvas.renderAll();
};

var offsetYVal = 10;
var setShadowOffsetY = function (value) {
    value = offsetYVal+=5;
    setActiveShadow('offsetY', value);
    canvas.renderAll();
};
var offBlurVal = 10;
var setShadowBlur = function (value) {
    value =  offBlurVal += 5;
    setActiveShadow('blur', value);
    canvas.renderAll();
};

var setShadowColor = function (value) {
    value = 'blue';
    setActiveShadow('color', value);
    canvas.renderAll();
};

var shadowify = function () {
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (!obj) return;

    if (obj.shadow) {
        obj.shadow = null;
    } else {
        obj.setShadow({
            color: "#000000",
            blur: 10,
            offsetX: 10,
            offsetY: 10
        });
    }
    canvas.renderAll();
};

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  left:50,
  top:50,
  width:100,
  height:100,
  fill:'blue'

}))
```

```css
canvas {
 border: blue dotted 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.18/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button onclick='shadowify()'>shadowify</button>
<button onclick='setShadowOffsetX()'>setShadowOffsetX</button>
<button onclick='setShadowOffsetY()'>setShadowOffsetY</button>
<button onclick='setShadowBlur()'>setShadowBlur</button>
<button onclick='setShadowColor()'>setShadowColor</button>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas><br>
```

`setShadow` creates a object of `fabric.Shadow`, so when you want to change the property just get the object using `object.shadow` and apply property to shadow object.

Comment: Perfect Sir! The trick was in the "function setActiveShadow" section. Working now exactly how I have expected (by defining "offsetX" et. in a $scope as in my previous code. Thank you very much mate!

Comment: – not sure how to get the value in `function getActiveShadow` - could you please give a helping hand?

Comment: Try return `object.shadow[name]`

Comment: I was trying with this `function getActiveShadow(name) {
    var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (!object) return '';
    return object.shadow[name] || '';
}`